# how to bind data to dropdown control in gridview

Tags: asp.net

i have  an  gridview  which i am binding to   datatable called  **dtimages**
 inside the  gridview i  have a dropdown control which is under  edit item template

so once the user clciks the edit  button  then the  dropdown control should get  binded  with  a  table  called **dtResource**
 and  all other   textbox  fields  which is under  different   **edititemtemplate** 
  will get  bind  with the datatable **dtimages**

so how  to  bind  these dropdown  control  with  different table
  thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the OnDataBinding event for the dropdownlist.

```
// In your aspx page
<asp:DropDownList ID="yourDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="yourTextFieldName" DataValueField="yourValueFieldName" OnDataBinding="yourDDL_DataBinding">
</asp:DropDownList>

// In your codebehind .cs file
protected void yourDDL_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
    // This could be a List of objects, DataTable, DataSet, whatever
    ddl.DataSource = GetCachedData();  
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

The `GetCachedData()` is something you should have so that you are not building or hitting the database each time to get the result that your ddl is being bound to.  This is not required though, you could hit the database each time but it cache it reduces the workload each time you switch to edit mode.